# Magento Database Stripping Down

Tags: magento-1.9, database

Maybe the title is poorly worded please let me know, but here is the scenario.

I have been tasked with migrating a magento store onto a new server and to tidy it up a bit, one thing I have noticed in the database were extensions that arent being used. for example multiple SMTP extensions being installed (looks potentially like a trial and error effort).

Now in an ideal world I would like to send the database over and strip out what would effectively be tables that aren't being used.

Is there a way to see what tables aren't being utilized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to automatically do this. You'll have to audit each of the extensions manually and determine what's being used or not being used.

First place is to look into `app/etc/modules` and start with the ones that are set to `<active>false</active>`.

Comment: Hi Music, Thanks for this, I didnt think there would be however I thought I would ask, the only other thing i could think of is pull off an excel version and do mass correlations strip it down, but thank you for your help!